# Partial template deduction in template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following structs:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct A {};

template<typename T>
struct B {};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct C {};
```

and want to use them as follows:

```
C<B<int>, A<double, B<int>>> c;
```

Is there any way to deduce the second template parameter for `A`, such that I can use it like this?

```
C<B<int>, A<double>> c;
```

This should work for any template arguments of `C` and not just for a particular one (therefore default arguments don't seem to work).

Furthermore a solution for variadic templates would be even better, so instead of

```
C<B<int>, A<double, B<int>>, A<float, A<double, B<int>>>> c;
```

something like this would be nice:

```
C<B<int>, A<double>, A<float>> c;
```

Comment: You may have a default second argument

Comment: @Ayxan Maybe my question was unclear. See the edit.

Comment: You're going to have to change something because `A<OneType>` is never going to be valid for `A` being defined to have two non-defaulted type parameters. It's really hard for me to say what compromise could/should be made without having any idea of the context.

Comment: @chris yes, but is there any way of deducing the second argument? Just as I could deduce it during the construction of `A<First, Second>`.

Comment: My guess is that it's possible to get _almost_ what you want without all that much extra metaprogramming behind the scenes to accomplish it. So yes, that would avoid repeating type names. However, perhaps there's a pattern you expect from all of these usages that would be a more natural fit. For example, maybe it's always `C<Type1, Template<Type2, Type1>, Template<Type3, Template<Type2, Type1>>, ...>`. That would lead to a syntax like `C<B<int>, A, double, float>` or similar pretty easily. Or perhaps more like `C<B<int>, Special<A, double, float>, Special<D, int, char>>`. I don't know yet.

Comment: @chris Thanks. If you would find some time to make this an answer, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I actually have no idea what a solid answer entails yet. That's my point. There's a potential fun little metaprogramming problem here, but I'd need more information to solve it.

Comment: Well, actually, **no**, because there's nothing mandating the identity of the B's. You either want @RSahu's answer, or maybe just change class C to depend on the "actual" two types it depends on (in your example - int and double).

Comment: But... wait a minute. Why do you even want to do this? Especially the variadic version? What's the scenario in which you would use the three-template-parameter version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of template metaprogramming fun, I was able to solve your problem both for the two-parameter and the variadic case (although in a somewhat narrow way):

```
// TypeList stuff

template<class... Args>
struct List {
    template<class Arg>
    using Add = List<Args..., Arg>;
};

template<class List> struct TailI;
template<class A, class... Ar> struct TailI<List<A, Ar...>> {
    using type = typename TailI<List<Ar...>>::type;
};

template<class A> struct TailI<List<A>> {
    using type = A;
};


template<class List>
using Tail = typename TailI<List>::type;

template<template<class...> class OP, class List> struct rename_impl;
template<template<class...> class OP, class... ListArgs>
struct rename_impl<OP, List<ListArgs...>> {
    using type = OP<ListArgs...>;
};

template<template<class...> class OP, class List>
using rename = typename rename_impl<OP, List>::type;

// Actual code solving problem at hand    
template<class T1, class T2> struct A{};

template<class... Args> struct C{};

template<class Built, class Next, class... Rest>
struct builder {
    using NewBuilt = typename Built::template Add<A<Next, Tail<Built>>>;
    using type = typename builder<NewBuilt, Rest...>::type;
};

template<class Built, class Next>
struct builder<Built, Next> {
    using NewBuilt = typename Built::template Add<A<Next, Tail<Built>>>;
    using type = rename<C, NewBuilt>;
};


template<class First, class... Rest>
using c_builder = typename builder<List<First>, Rest...>::type;

using t = c_builder<int, double, float>;

// Test driver
#include <utility>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<t, C<int, A<double, int>, A<float, A<double, int>>>>, "");
```

Comment: Why is this better than @RSahu's simple solution?

Comment: @einpoklum, for starters, `I haven't thought through how that can be extended to support a variadic class template C,` - this does support variadic C, as can be seen in the test driver example.

Answer (score 2):

For the simpler case of

```
template<typename A, typename B> struct C {};
```

you can use a helper class to provide you the type you need.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct C_Helper
{
   using type = C<B<T1>, A<T2, B<T1>>>;
};
```

and use

```
using C_Type = typename C_Helper<int, double>::type;
C_Type c;
```

I haven't thought through how that can be extended to support a variadic class template `C`,